# EXCEL VBA LOCKED COLUMN ISSUE

Tags: excel, vba

i need to lock the column if the column heading contain" locked" in the worksheet. howwever, i can only find VBA that do on only 1 column but i need the VBA applies to all column. below is my findings on locked one single column. can anyone write me a VBA for applies to all column.
[VBA Code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elHOt.png)

Comment: Consider using the "add source code" functionality to directly paste your code in your question

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

You can set the columns according to your needs like A:XFD

```
'To locked the columns
[A:Z].Locked = True

'To unlocked the columns
[A:Z].Locked = False
```